# Blender opens to some crazy colors

Tags: osx

I'm on an older mac and am running into an issue trying to open Blender RC2. I have iOS 10.11.6. I downloaded Blender and when opening I get a lot of pastel color gradients over most of the UI. Anyone else run into this issue? Some Google-ing didn't turn up anything. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Can you add which Mac model you have, also is everything up to date?

Comment: It's a mac pro from 2009. Everything is as up to date as hardware will allow.

Comment: It could be that your card isn't supported. Check your OpenGL version, and the requirements for your version of blender.

Comment: Yep, looks like my iOS does not support the newer OpenGL.
https://code.blender.org/2019/04/supported-gpus-in-blender-2-80/
Thanks for the tip Jorge!